# error installing python extension in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, azure, dbeaver, azure-postgresql

I have a postgresql database that is in production within azure, I want to install a python extension on this database
i use database manager called DBeaver
with it I run the command:

```
CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u;
```

but I get the error:

```
could not open extension control file "/usr/local/pgsql/share/extension/plpythonu.control": No such file or directory
```

I'm still a beginner and I don't know how to solve this problem..
I tried to install python on my computer, and it is installed correctly
I tried running the command:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_extension WHERE extname = 'plpython3u';
```

to see if it was already installed, and it is not, because it returns an empty table
How can I resolve the error and correctly install the python extension?

i am using windows 11

Comment: You can't. You can read the docs [Postgresql extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-extensions#postgres-14-extensions) where you will find that `plpython3u` is not available. Probably due the  `u` at the end of extension name which stands for untrusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error installing python extension in postgresql

I appreciate @Adrian Klaver's explanation.

You wish to add the plpython3u extension to PostgreSQL databases, as I understand it.

You may see a list of all supported extensions here:

> Open Portal >>Go to your Azure Database for PostgreSQL >> Settings >> Server Parameters >> search for azure.extensions. >> you will see below list.

[image]

AFAIK, we are not able to add an extension beyond the list provided by Microsoft in azure PostgreSQL Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-extensions).